# How to display row from page ID

Tags: php

I am very new and trying to get from the url ie

```
device.php?id=2
```

and use the id number multiple times.

can anyone tell me how to display this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$id = (int)$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 1):

1) [Get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) the ID.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

2) Search for $id in your database, using MySQL functions like mysqli_fetch_array() etc.

3) Echo the values you fetched, using simple HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql= mysql_query("select * from tableName where id = $id ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $row['columnName'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be in `$_GET["id"]`.

Comment: $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id LIKE '$_GET["id"]'"); Ive tried this

Comment: Solved by this. Thank Guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```